# Complexity class of finding the number of walks of length $k$ that have different vertex sets

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Vertex set $A$ is of the form: $A = \{(v_1,r_1),(v_2,r_2),...\}$ where $v_1 \in V$ and $r_1$ refers to the number of times $v_1$ is reached in some walk and $v_j \neq v_i$ whenever $i \neq j$.

Suppose that one wants to count the number of distinct vertex sets that each have $\sum_i r_i = k$ and are allowed by some walk in a graph.

What would be complexity class of this? I was not really able to find complexity class for it. Would this problem be in #P-complete or just in #P?

Comment: So, essentially, you want the number of walks in a graph that visit a total of k nodes, repetition allowed, and counting the start and end vertices? Maybe my formulation makes for some double-counting, as one could traverse a walk in either direction and end up with the same vertex set? Am I correct in my interpretation?

Comment: Yes - you are absolutely right there.

Comment: Isn't the decision problem then in P? You could just run a BFS from each vertex until you find a path of the correct length (really naive algorithm, but surely poly-time). The counting problem would then belong to the class #P ("sharp-P").

Comment: I mean, yeah. I was thinking of the following decision problem: "Would the count be greater than $b$?" For the counting version, would this be in #P-complete or just #P?